# How to set the size in pixels in the truetype() function of the Pillow library?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, truetype

How can I keep the actual text size the same for different fonts. That is, I want the text written by the ImageDraw.Draw().Text() function to be the same size, for example 48 pixels. To specify the size of the text, I pass the number of POINTS to the ImageFont.TrueType() function, but the points for each font are different. Here's a quick summary: if the size of the text written in the font Arial = 48 pixels and = 56 points, this does not mean that the text written in Times New Romans with a size of 56 points will be equal to 48 pixels. My task is to make sure that I can somehow translate these 48 pixels into n points for any font.

I Added a picture to clearly convey my problem
[image]

This is the REPREX of my code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

line_height = 48
image = Image.new('RGB', (60, 60), 'white')
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
drawer.line(((0, 8), (59, 8)), width=1, fill='black')
drawer.line(((0, 8 + line_height), (59, 8 + line_height)), width=1, fill='black')
font = ImageFont.truetype(r'C:\Windows\Fonts\ariali.ttf',
                          size=line_height)  # size should be in points but I don't now, how to do it
drawer.text((0, 8), 'help', fill='black', font=font)
image.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matching *em* size

This is easy, since font sizes are normally measured in terms of the *em* height, which is typically the maximum height from the highest accent marks on top of capital letters, to the lowest descenders on lowercase letters. So when you set the font size to 72 points in a desktop publishing application, it's the *em* size that will measure 72 points, not the letters themselves, since letters vary in size.

Use the `size` parameter to set the font size for each font, like this:

```
fontSize = 10
ImageFont.truetype("Helvetica.ttf", size=fontSize)
ImageFont.truetype("Times New Roman.ttf", size=fontSize)
ImageFont.truetype("Roboto.otf", size=fontSize)
```

This will render each font in the same point size. Note that the letter proportions vary from one font to another, so some fonts may look a bit larger or smaller, and the vertical proportions of the font will also affect the position of the baseline.

## Matching vertical metrics between fonts

This is much more complicated. You'll need to look up the metrics tables inside each font file, and then do some simple math to resize according to whatever metrics you're trying to match. Do you want the baselines to align, or do you want the lowercase letters to be the same height, or capital letters to be the same height? You can't match everything because each font will have different vertical proportions.

### Getting vertical metrics via `fontTools`

Here's a function I've used in the past that will get you started. Be sure to `pip install fonttools` first.

```
from fontTools import ttLib

def get_vmetrics(fontPath):
    '''
    Get vertical metrics from a font file
    '''
    font = ttLib.TTFont(fontPath)
    metrics = {
        'upm': font['head'].unitsPerEm,
        'yMin': font['head'].yMin,
        'yMax': font['head'].yMax,
        'capHeight': font['OS/2'].sCapHeight,
        'xHeight': font['OS/2'].sxHeight,
        'ascender': font['OS/2'].sTypoAscender,
        'descender': font['OS/2'].sTypoDescender,
        'leading': font['OS/2'].sTypoLineGap,
    }
    return metrics
```

### References

`fontTools` is reasonably well documented, and you can learn how the tables inside a font are structured with the included `ttx` command line tool, which converts a binary font file to XML.

- [fontTools on GitHub](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)
- [fontTools docs](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/)
- [HEAD table – OpenType spec at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/head)
- [OS/2 table – OpenType spec at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2)

Comment: Well, I need the text to display the same size in any font. How do I calculate these size variations for different fonts?

Comment: I've expanded my answer substantially to show you how to get the vertical metrics of a font.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer, now I will understand it)) I'm creating a program for generating prescriptions. I hope for help with questions from a specialist like you

Comment: Hello again, I have more or less figured out the font table, but I can't make sense of the Em unit. I read a lot of sites, but I didn't have a clear idea of how to work with it. Can you help me understand?

Comment: How do I prevent the letter proportions issue?. I want them to be equal to my specified fontsize